# How to upgrade wall panels?

Tags: walls, wood, remodeling

I live in a house with wall panels like this:
[image]

This is not a wall paneling but a wood wall. (according to my wife, lol)

I'd like to convert this to something else because it makes the room very dark. I was thinking of painting it white but I worry it won't look good. Another option could be drywall but with this I will need to remove door moldings and do many adjustments since drywall might be too thick.

I was thinking of gluing floor planks or something similar but I see many comments saying it won't stay and will peel. I guess I could nail the laminate flooring but that's basically wood on wood which doesn't really solve the problem and it might end up expensive.

Another options could be normal ceramic tiles but again I don't think the cement will attach to the wood since it seems it's treated with something.

Are there any other nice modern options that can be done with it without any larger remodel?

I was also thinking gluing wallpaper or drywall liner and then paining but I don't know how well it will hold up. And I would need to fill up the connection with something so it won't tear the paper. (I think this would be the best option but I'm not sure if it will work).

Comment: Make sure wife is happy with thinking about covering up beautiful wood panels.

Comment: @crip659, she is not, she likes them too but it makes the living room very dark. I feel like we are living in the dungeon. The picture is not from my house.

Comment: Wifey not happy, you never will be happy.  Would recommend a very good cleaning first, years of life might have darken them.  A floor closer to white/pale might brighten the room and make a happy home.

Comment: The distinction is that if you remove the wood pretty-bits, you are looking at studs.   If it was a wall covering, you'd be looking at drywall.  (And this matters because drywall is a firestop, *and wood isn't*.)

Comment: Personally I think they are gorgeous, covering them reminds me of the times when ppl would cover  beautiful wood floors with wall to wall carpet only to be uncovered and refinished by later owners.  IMHO,  Add more lighting, LEDs cost pennies to run these days and enjoy that gorgeous wood.  This is just a comment not an answer and opinion based.

Comment: Pop that outlet cover off and you may be able to see if there is drywall behind the wood.

Comment: @JonCuster, I know what is behind. 2x2 studs. No drywall. The panels make the actual walls.

Comment: The answers below (from "this is beautiful" to "ugh, hideous!") are why decorating questions are off topic. Surprised that this has lasted 17 hours without being closed...

Answer (score 5):

That is knotty pine paneling.

Whether or not it is installed directly on studs or if there is drywall support behind it is outside the scope of this answer.

Asking "How to make this better?" is very subjective and ultimately there's no single right answer.

You need to figure out precisely what about the paneling is desirable. If she really likes the knots then painting and wallpaper are definitely out of the question.

However, there are a few options.

If the goal is to liven up the room then these choices *could* suffice:

**Lighten the color**

Sandblast it back to bare wood. An orbital sander would work too but is slower and good luck with the grooves.

Apply a lighter stain, bleach the wood, or leave it be depending on your preference. Applying polyurethane is highly recommended.

Applying water polyurethane will maintain the precise color.

Oil polyurethane will add an amber hue.

**Introduce more light**

Can you install another window or two?

Can you install some recessed lights?

**Lessen the amount of wood #1**

You can choose to remove just the bottom or top half of paneling, install drywall, and paint with a lighter color. The seam can be covered with chair rails.

I would call this choice "knotty pine wainscoting".

**Lessen the amount of wood #2**

Remove 3 walls worth of the paneling and install drywall. The remaining 4th wall will be your "accent wall".

Comment: I'd add "bleaching" the wood to the list of "still wood, lighter, wife might not be unhappy about" options. Happy wife, happy life...

Comment: @Ecnerwal I hesitated to answer this question because there is a myriad of techniques that I'm simply not aware of. Added bleaching to my answer though =)

Comment: You did well. I don't know about Grasper's wife, but some spouses would consider painting that a divorce-worthy offense, so it's a tricky question. As for *wallpapering* it, Grasper wouldn't want me on the jury...

Comment: @Ecnerwal I appreciate that. We definitely don't know all of the conversations which have transpired but hopefully this gives OP a sense of direction when looking for finished product examples on the Internet! One of my later edits did mentioned how paint/wallpaper is out of the question.

Comment: hmm, yeah I considered staining it with a white stain. But I don't really want to sand it. It will be mess and dust everywhere. Do I need to sand it?

Comment: @Grasper A bit tongue-in-cheek but if you do it wrong then I defer to the classic "looks good from my house!" I won't lose any sleep over it. If you wish to do it right then sanding it is the only choice. Like I said, you have not explained what your wife likes about the existing paneling.

Comment: We like it(not just my wife) because it looks like a nice piece of furniture from certain angles and when the light is just right. But as I said the house look old like from 1970s and we would want to modernize it since I already put a new light grey laminate flooring with the electric heating...All left are the walls...

Comment: @Grasper Then go ahead and do it. If you need to simply paint over the existing panel then use shellac primer.

Answer (score 5):

I hear you on the low light levels, but that's because **you're lighting the room wrong**.

The walls in a normal off-white room have an albedo (light bounce) of 80-90%. Thus, most light hitting the walls bounces back.  Albedo drops off drastically, and those walls might have a 10-25% albedo, so they are "black holes for light".

You're lighting it like a normal off-white walled room. And yeah, your light is just "going away".

Remember those cheap *Halogen torchieres* that were all the rage in the 80s-90s, and then all the houses kept burning down, and people realized the things are *500 watts each* and very wasteful?  **You want the LED version of that**, which will not be hot, won't start fires, and will take like 30-50 watts.  (buy new, or get old torchieres and convert them - lots of videos on that.)

It'll bounce nicely off of the white ceiling and give you lots of light.  It will simply overwhelm the low albedo of the walls.

Colors come in temperatures. Avoid the "cold" LED temperatures like 4000-6000K, those are for workspace lighting.  You can get LEDs in the 2000-3000K "warm" temperatures that match a "hearth and home" vibe. 2000K is campfire. 2700K old incandescent. 3000K is halogens, and that's as cold as you want to get.

Since it's all bounce light, you get an effect similar to *cove lighting* which is soft and wonderful.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I meant during the day light. The room is fine during the dark time. I'm already using GUI LED spot lights, dimmable and those are good enough. It's really about the day when we don't need lights. It's like in the middle. I don't want to turn the lights on during the day. Our house have trees around and they block a lot of light during summer. In the winter when leaves are off it's all much lighter but the days are shorter. I also wanted the house to look more modern since I already put a new light gray laminate flooring with electric heating. to finish the modern look

Comment: @Grasper That look is pretty 1970s, yeah.  House fashion, who invented that?  Remodelers I'm sure.  I'll stick to my Victorians. Complete with cabinet door behind tub faucet for easy servicing.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do:

- Paint. Make sure you use a good sealing primer, otherwise the knots will bleed through.
- Sand the wood and refinish with clear poly. This should lighten it quite a bit.
- Remove the wood, and see what's underneath. It's probably drywall or plaster; if that's still in good shape, you can paint it, otherwise rip it out and put up new drywall.

What you **should not** do:

- Wallpaper. You won't be able to get it into the grooves between the boards.
- Tile over the wood panels. Wood isn't rigid enough to serve as a base for tiles.

Answer (score 0):

Seal it with something like Zinsser All Prime. Then paint it.  Did that in one of my first homes and got rave reviews from friends and neighbors. ( even after wife said it could not be done.)

Comment: Won't the knots blead through it. Will they be still visible? Do you have a picture of your work? Did it lighten up the room?

Comment: I would do surface prep first.  Bigtime.  As for covering the knots, that is the job of primer and prep.  The knots will be covered by your last coat of primer. (meaning if they still show, you're not done with prep & priming).  Will it lighten the room? Yes, because it's white.

Comment: @Grasper the sealer/ primer is to seal the knot holes and the surface so you can paint without bleed-through.  Google the product. It tells you everything you want to know. Sorry no pics, that was 35 yrs ago. But I have painted paneling in other homes with the same great results. If the knot holes have splits and other textures and you want a smooth surface, spackle them, and sand lightly before you seal, then paint

Comment: Of course, this still leaves a "panel" textured wall. The previous owners of our house covered thin wood paneling with white paint and wall paper. You can still see the paneling through both. We covered some of it with a _very_ 90s pattern that is more than busy enough to hide the lines - until you get close. We don't have a lot of wall space in our old farm house (all windows and doors), but this would be a huge wall of "white painted wood paneling" that would stand out immediately.